# C++ function pointer and member function pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Is there a way to use a function pointer for both functions and member functions?

I want to create a kind of event-handle which can hold member functions of a class and at the same time it should be capable to have "normal" function pointers.

EDIT: I have found a solution. Probably not the best one but one;

Event.h

```
#include <map>

class BasicEvent {

public:

    BasicEvent(int id) : eventId(id)
    {}

    int GetId() const
    { 
        return eventId;
    }

    virtual void ObjectMethode() {}

protected:

    const int eventId;

};

class BasicEventHandler {

public:

    void Trigger(BasicEvent* event)
    {
        if (this->eventMap.find(event->GetId()) != this->eventMap.end()) {
            eventMap[event->GetId()](event);
        }
    }

    void AddEvent(int id, std::function<int(BasicEvent*)> eventFunction)
    {
        eventMap[id] = eventFunction;
    }

    void RemoveEvent(int id)
    {
        this->eventMap.erase(id);
    }

private:

    std::map<int, std::function<int(BasicEvent*)>> eventMap;

};
```

main.cpp

```
class CustomEvent : public BasicEvent {

public:

    CustomEvent(int id) : tq::BasicEvent(id)
    {
    x = 9;
    y = 8;
    }

    struct {
    int x;
    int y;
};

    void ObjectMethode()
    {
    std::cout << this->eventId << " Custom Event: X: " << x << " Y: " << y << '\n';
    }

};


int main() {
    BasicEventHandler myHandler;

    myHandler.AddEvent(0, [&](BasicEvent* event) {
        std::cout << " EVENT <" << event->GetId() << "> Triggered!\n";
    return 0;
    });

    myHandler.AddEvent(1, [&](tq::BasicEvent* event) {
    event->ObjectMethode();
    return 0;
    });

    myHandler.Trigger(&BasicEvent(0));
    myHandler.Trigger(&CustomEvent(1));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't you use [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?  See also [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [std::invoke](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke).

Comment: I don't think so. I will now provide two solutions. One for class members and one for funtions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where will the member function get its "this" pointer?
the two functions cannot have the same signature.
Probably, your best bet will be to create a lambda, that will capture the "this", and send it to your event-handler.

`std::function` will be able to hold it for you.

Answer (score 2):

C++11 and Lambdas .. yay!!

So here we go..

Let us have a function, your event handler which will take a **predicate**(a function that returns true or false) and two functions namely `on_sucess` and `on_error`.

If the `test_predicate` returns `true` then `on_success` shall be invoked, else `on_error` would be invoked.

```
template<typename Predicate, typename OnSucess, typename OnError>
void single_event_handler (Predicate && test_predicate,
                           OnSucess  && on_success,
                           OnError   && on_error)
{
    if( test_predicate() )
        on_success();
    else
        on_error();
}
```

And now our caller side.
Here we have 3 functions that we want to fit into this pattern.

```
bool is_even(int num) { return !(num % 2); }
void on_even_found() { std::cout << "Number passed is even\n"; }
void on_odd_found() { std::cout << "Number passed is odd\n"; };
```

But as you can see, the `is_even` function does not fit into the signature of `test_predicate`. `is_even(int)` takes a single argument, while `test_predicate()` takes none.

So how do we fix this ?

We wrap it into one more function and/or lambda, and then pass it.

Guiding Principle : **Every problem can be solved by adding one more layer.**

```
// wrap it in another function or lambda
auto is_5_even = []() { return is_even(5); };
auto is_4_even = []() { return is_even(4); };
```

And now once all the pieces of our puzzle is ready, we create our own event handler.

```
// caller side - pair the final structure
single_event_handler(is_5_even, on_even_found, on_odd_found);
single_event_handler(is_4_even, on_even_found, on_odd_found);
```

Now this code can be implemented in pre C++11, by using bind and function pointer.
Sadly `std::bind` and `std::function` were introduced in C++11 and you would have to use other alternatives such as boost library.

Moreover, another wrapper can be written on top of `single_event_handler` which can manage multiple events at once, but I think we will have to create another function `register_event` so that it can be used effectively.

Here is the full working code, for your reference (compiled using `g++ -std=c++11`)

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Predicate, typename OnSucess, typename OnError>
void single_event_handler (Predicate && test_predicate,
                           OnSucess  && on_success,
                           OnError   && on_error)
{
    if( test_predicate() )
        on_success();
    else
        on_error();
}

bool is_even(int num) { return !(num % 2); }
void on_even_found() { std::cout << "Number passed is even\n"; }
void on_odd_found() { std::cout << "Number passed is odd\n"; };

int main()
{
    // caller side
    auto is_5_even = []() { return is_even(5); };
    auto is_4_even = []() { return is_even(4); };

    single_event_handler(is_5_even, on_even_found, on_odd_found);
    single_event_handler(is_4_even, on_even_found, on_odd_found);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Really, thank you alot. But actually my needs look a bit different.

Here is the concept I think off  
 `void (*eventClose)(EventType&);      // <- Shall be capable of holding function and member function pointer`

Comment: Then you are better off by using lambdas or bind, with your prescribed interface. :) Yes, now my answer seems irrelevant to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Accept your handler as a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), and clients can then pass in whatever they want. Be it functions, lambdas, other functors, you name it.

The template will handle the details for you, and the clients can choose how they wish to be called.