# How to avoid duplicates using inheritance or polymorphism, best way to refactor

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism, refactoring

I have a class Operation

```
Class Operation {
virtual void execute(Operation, OperationCallback) = 0
}
```

With a callback

```
using OperationCallback = std::function<void(Error)>;
```

and like 30 different classes extending from it

```
InsertOperation : public Operation
EditOperation : public Operation
```

Each of them implemented execute and sets the callback at the end of the operation

I execute the operation using

```
void ExecuteOperation(Operation operation, OperationCallback operationCallback){
operation->execute(operation, operationCallback);
}
```

I want to have a new callback called Result which includes an Error and an Id

```
Class Result{

Error error
int id;

Error getError()
Int getId()

}
```

The new callback will only be used in some operations and not all of them

But I would like to reuse the existing code so I do not have to duplicate a lot of the methods to use the new callback

AVOID DUPLICATE like

```
using OperationWithResultCallback = std::function<void(Result)>;

void ExecuteOperationWithResult(Operation operation, OperationCallback operationCallback)
{
operation-> executeWithResult(operation, operationCallback);
}

In Operation Classs
virtual void executeWithResult(Operation, OperationWithResultCallback) = 0
```

There might be an option for Result to extend Error but then I will have to change to use the reference &Error everywhere

Also I can probably add the id to the Error class itself but I want to avoid that.

Is there any other way I can use Result only in the Operations that I need it but still keep the Error parameter everywhere??

Comment: Seems like you are new to C++. I feel you are over complicating the interface by adding too much inheritance(which is not required). C++ has a lot of different paradigms. Have you read about template and/or used them previously? If yes, try to give a read to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632263/c-function-pointer-and-member-function-pointer/49636209#49636209). If it makes sense, then we can work towards refactoring your problem.

Comment: Templates is the option to go, Thanks for the hint.